# Making sure if Caffe is using multiple-GPUs

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I am new to using training neural networks. I have access to GPU cluster and I am fine-tuning a version of Alex-Net for scene classification.

I have access to two GPUs right now and I want to use both of them for training. nvidia-smi command gives me the id of the GPUs (which are 0 and 1).

This is how I do the training to use both of the GPUs:
     caffe.set_mode_gpu()
     caffe.set_device([0,1])

Is this the right way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python allows you to choose a single GPU using `set_device()`. Multi-GPU is only supported on the C++ interface. The `--gpu` flag used for this purpose is discussed [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/multigpu.md). The GPUs to be used for training can be set with the `--gpu` flag on the command line to the `Caffe` tool. For example,

```
build/tools/caffe train --solver=models/bvlc_alexnet/solver.prototxt --gpu=0,1
```

will train on GPUs 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal you can type like that:

```
python yourpythonfile.py CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0, 1
```